# XPath normalize-space() to return a sequence of normalized strings

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I need to use the XPath function normalized-space() to normalize the text I want to extract from a XHTML document: http://test.anahnarciso.com/clean_bigbook_0.html

I'm using the following expression:

```
//*[@slot="address"]/normalize-space(.)
```

Which works perfectly in Qizx Studio, the tool I use to test XPath expressions.

```
    let $doc := doc('http://test.anahnarciso.com/clean_bigbook_0.html')
    return $doc//*[@slot="address"]/normalize-space(.)
```

This simple query returns a sequence of `xs:string`.

```
144 Hempstead Tpke
403 West St
880 Old Country Rd
8412 164th St
8412 164th St
1 Irving Pl
1622 McDonald Ave
255 Conklin Ave
22011 Hempstead Ave
7909 Queens Blvd
11820 Queens Blvd
1027 Atlantic Ave
1068 Utica Ave
1002 Clintonville St
1002 Clintonville St
1156 Hempstead Tpke
Route 49
10007 Rockaway Blvd
12694 Willets Point Blvd
343 James St
```

Now, I want to use the previous expression in my Java code.

```
String exp = "//*[@slot=\"address"\"]/normalize-space(.)";
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(exp);
Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

But the last line throws an Exception:

`Cannot convert XPath value to Java object: required class is org.w3c.dom.NodeList; supplied value has type xs:string`

Obvsiously, I should change `XPathConstants.NODESET` for something; I tried `XPathConstants.STRING` but it only returns the first element of the sequence.

How can I obtain something like an array of Strings?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your expression works in XPath 2.0, but is illegal in XPath 1.0 (which is used in Java) - it should be `normalize-space(//*[@slot='address'])`.

Anyway, in XPath 1.0, when `normalize-space()` is called on a node-set, only the first node (in document order) is taken.

In order to do what you want to do, you'll need to use a XPath 2.0 compatible parser, or traverse the resulting node-set and call `normalize-space()` on every node:

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
XPathExpression expr;

String select = "//*[@slot='address']";
expr = xpath.compile(select);
NodeList result = (NodeList)expr.evaluate(input, XPathConstants.NODESET);

String normalize = "normalize-space(.)";
expr = xpath.compile(normalize);

int length = result.getLength();
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    System.out.println(expr.evaluate(result.item(i), XPathConstants.STRING));
}
```

...outputs exactly your given output.

Comment: Thank you, your response was very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what version of XPath you're using. Check out this post, hopefully it'll answer your question: [Is it possible to apply normalize-space to all nodes XPath expression finds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359512/is-it-possible-to-apply-normalize-space-to-all-nodes-xpath-expression-finds) Good luck.

Comment: That's it, thank you. I searched similar questions but I did not find that one. It seems like I'm going to use Saxon after all...

Answer (score 3):

As you noted, the XPath 2.0 expression `//*[@slot="address"]/normalize-space(.)` returns a sequence of strings. This return type is not supported by the JAXP `XPathConstants` class, because the JAXP interfaces were not designed to support XPath 2.0.

This leaves you with two choices:

1. Use an XPath 2.0 processor that has [native interfaces for XPath 2.0](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/xpath-api/s9api-xpath.xml) or that can [convert sequences to a return type supported by JAXP](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/xpath/XPathExpressionImpl.html#evaluate%28java.lang.Object,%20javax.xml.namespace.QName%29)
2. Use only XPath 1.0 expressions. For example, in your case you could simply select the target nodes:

   ```
   //*[@slot="address"]
   ```

   And then iterate the resulting nodeset, collecting the results into an array or `List`.

Note that it's important to distinguish between the *processer* you're using to evaluate the expression and the *interface* you're using to initiate the evaluation.

Answer (score 3):

**The expression**:

```
//*[@slot="address"]/normalize-space(.)
```

is syntactically legal (and practically useful) XPath 2.0 expression.

The same expression is not syntactically legal in XPath 1.0 -- it isn't allowed for a location step to be a function call.

In fact, it isn't possible to write a *single* XPath 1.0 expression the result of whose evaluation is the wanted set of strings.

You need to use in your program a product that implements XPath 2.0 -- such as Saxon 9.x.

Comment: Thank you for that information, I didn't know that XPath 1.0 was so limited. I've already tried Saxon, but I found it a little more complex than JAXP.

Comment: @anahnarciso: If you mean that XPath 2.0 is more complex than the version of XPath (1.0) that JAXP provides interfaces for, this is probably true. If, on the other side, you mean that Saxon is more difficult to invoke, I am not so sure. I perform many transformations with Saxon on a daily basis -- it is trivial to invoke Saxon from the command line.

Comment: I mean, because I'm so used to JAXP and I was trying to avoid using another external library. The best Saxon Java code example I found was the one available in the official website. Do you know any other useful resources/tutorials about Saxon?