# How to parse this provided XML with java.xml.xpath?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I am trying to parse this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<veranstaltungen>
  <veranstaltung id="201611211500#25045271">
    <titel>Mal- und Zeichen-Treff</titel>
    <start>2016-11-21 15:00:00</start>
    <veranstaltungsort id="20011507">
      <name>Freizeitclub - ganz unbehindert </name>
      <anschrift>Macht los e.V.
Lipezker Straße 48
03048 Cottbus
</anschrift>
      <telefon>xxxx xxxx </telefon>
      <fax>0355 xxxx</fax>
[...]
</veranstaltungen>
```

As you can see, some of the texts have whitespace or even linebreaks. I am having issues with the text from the node `anschrift`, because I need to find the right location data in a database. Problem is, the returned String is:

```
Macht los e.V.Lipezker Straße 4803048 Cottbus
```

instead of:

```
Macht los e.V. Lipezker Straße 48 03048 Cottbus
```

I know the correct way to parse it should be with `normalie-space()` but I cannot quite work out how to do it. I tried this:

```
// Does not work; afaik because xpath 1 normalizes just the first node
xPath.compile("normalize-space(veranstaltungen/veranstaltung[position()=1]/veranstaltungsort/anschrift/text()"));

// Does not work
xPath.compile("veranstaltungen/veranstaltung[position()=1]/veranstaltungsort[normalize-space(anschrift/text())]"));
```

I also tried the solution given here: [xpath-normalize-space-to-return-a-sequence-of-normalized-strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11378372/xpath-normalize-space-to-return-a-sequence-of-normalized-strings)

```
xPathExpression = xPath.compile("veranstaltungen/veranstaltung[position()=1]/veranstaltungsort");
NodeList result = (NodeList) xPathExpression.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

String normalize = "normalize-space(.)";
xPathExpression = xPath.compile(normalize);

int length = result.getLength();
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    System.out.println(xPathExpression.evaluate(result.item(i), XPathConstants.STRING));
}
```

System.out prints:

```
Macht los e.V.Lipezker Straße 4803048 Cottbus
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

I have a workaround already, but this can't be the solution. The following few lines show how I put the String together from the HTTPResponse:

```
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), Charset.forName(charset)))) {
  final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
  String              line;

  while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    // stringBuilder.append(line);
    // WORKAROUND: Add a space after each line
    stringBuilder.append(line).append(" ");
  }

  // Work with the red lines
}
```

I would rather have a solid solution.

Comment: `normalize-space()` strips leading and trailing whitespace and converts other sequences of whitespace characters (including newlines) into a single space character. As your result doesn't have a space between the lines of the text content of the `anschrift` element, something must eat your newlines *before* `normalize-space()` gets to do its job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of Markus, I was able to solve the issue. The reason was the readLine() method of the BufferedReader discarding line breaks. The following codesnippet works for me (Maybe it can be improved):

```
public Document getDocument() throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {

  final HttpResponse response = getResponse(); // returns a HttpResonse
  final HttpEntity   entity   = response.getEntity();
  final Charset      charset  = ContentType.getOrDefault(entity).getCharset();  

  // Not 100% sure if I have to close the InputStreamReader. But I guess so.
  try (InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent(), charset == null ? Charset.forName("UTF-8") : charset)) {
    return documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new InputSource(isr));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Originally, you seem to be using the following code for reading the XML:

```
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), Charset.forName(charset)))) {
  final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
  String              line;

  while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    stringBuilder.append(line);
  }

}
```

This is where your newlines get eaten: `readline()` does *not* return the trailing newline characters. If you then parse the contents of the `stringBuilder` object, you will get an incorrect DOM, where the text nodes do not contain the original newlines from the XML.

Comment: Didn't know this. Thank you for the info. My solution is then to check if the line ends with an '>' and if not adding a "&#xA;".

Comment: Don't do this. You're modifying the input again. Why do you want to do line based reading? Why not parse the input stream as is?

Comment: I should get my head clear for a while. You are right. Will do this now.