# Using normalize-space with Scrapy

Tags: python, parsing, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

Below is a mock-up of a document I'm working on:

```
<div>
<h4>Area</h4>
  <span class="aclass"> </span>
  <span class="bclass">
        <strong>Address:</strong>
  10 Downing Street

  London

  SW1
  </span>
</div>
```

I'm getting the address like this:

```
response.xpath(u".//h4[. = 'Area']/following-sibling::span[contains(.,'Address:')]/text()").extract()
```

which returns

```
[u'\r\n  \t', u'\r\n  10 Downing Street\r\n\r\n  London     \r\n  \r\n  SW1\r\n  ']
```

I'm trying to clean that up with normalize-space. I've tried putting it in every location I could think of, but it either tells me there's a syntax error, or returns an empty string.

**Updating** to add that I'm trying to get this working without changing the selector too much. I have similar cases which don't have the `<strong>` tag, for example. The selector is overcomplicated in the example I've prepared here, but in the live version, I have to take that rather convoluted route to get to the address.

**Regarding the possible duplicate** Following the advice in the possible duplicate, I added `/normalize-space(.)` giving this:

```
(u".//h4[. = 'Area']/following-sibling::span[contains(.,'Address:')]/text()/normalize-space(.)").extract()
```

That produces a `ValueError: Invalid XPath:` error.

Comment: Regarding the duplicate question reference: `.//h4[. = 'Area']/following-sibling::span[contains(.,'Address:')]/text()/normalize-space(.)` is valid in XPath 2, but **not in XPath 1.0** (which scrapy supports only, on top of lxml/libxml2). Citing the accepted answer [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359512/is-it-possible-to-apply-normalize-space-to-all-nodes-xpath-expression-finds): _"In XPath 2.0 a location step of an XPath expression may be a function reference"_. This is not possible with XPath 1.0

Comment: Another option is to use `normalize-space()` or `string()` on the `<span>` with the address and use regular expression chaining `.re(r)` with `r=re.compile(r'Address:(.*)', re.S)` or similar. `selector.xpath('.//h4[.="Area"]/following-sibling::span[starts-with(normalize-space(), "Address")]').xpath('string()').re(r)` would give you `[u'\n  10 Downing Street\n\n  London\n\n  SW1\n  ']` (I use `string()` because newlines can be important, and `normalize-space()` will replace them with space)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"normalize-space(//strong[contains(text(), 'Address:')]/following-sibling::node())"
```

Comment: The original version of you answer was similar to this:

(u"normalize-space(//h4[. = 'Area']/following-sibling::span[contains(.,'Address:')])").extract()

That actually seems to work. I was just wondering if you saw a particular problem with that. Is there any reason not to use it?

Answer (score 4):

You can locate the `strong` element, get the *following text sibling* and normalize it:

```
In [1]: response.xpath(u"normalize-space(.//strong[. = 'Address:']/following-sibling::text())").extract()
Out[1]: [u'10 Downing Street London SW1']
```

Alternatively, you can look into [Item Loaders](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html) and input and output processors. I often use [`Join()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#scrapy.loader.processors.Join), [`TakeFirst()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#scrapy.loader.processors.TakeFirst) and [`MapCompose(unicode.strip)`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#scrapy.loader.processors.MapCompose) for cleaning up the extracted data from extra newlines or spaces.

Comment: I feel that, depending on what you're doing with the data, Item Loaders would be the way to go.  This is one of the main thing it's designed to do - data sanitation/formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Scrapy you can simplify your XPath using a Python one-liner:

```
" ".join(s.split()) # where `s` is your string
```

Using the above you can omit `normalize-space` from your XPath expression and, instead, create a reusable sanitization function using [Scrapy Input Processors](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#declaring-input-and-output-processors) like so:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader.processors import MapCompose
from w3lib.html import remove_tags

def normalize_space(value):
    return " ".join(value.split())

class Product(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field(
        input_processor=MapCompose(remove_tags, normalize_space),
    )
```

Alternatively you could also use the Python expression inside a [Scrapy Item Loader](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html) like this:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.loader.processors import Compose

class ProductLoader(ItemLoader):
    name_in = Compose(lambda s: " ".join(s.split()))
```

Credit for the one-liner goes to [Tom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46501496/712334) in a related question.