# XPath seperator/divider

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0

Apologies for the poor explanation, as I'm no code expert.

Im extracting a piece of information which is layd out in tables such as this:
[image]

I need to extract each table for example from Consumer buy-to-let Business table i need the following:
Consumer buy-to-let arranger,Consumer buy-to-let advisor

My current XPath which extracts this information but without a comma looks like this:

```
//*/text()[normalize-space(.)='Consumer buy-to-let Business']/parent::*/parent::*/p
```

Output:

```
Consumer buy-to-let arrangerConsumer buy-to-let advisor
```

I'm struggling to find out how to add the comma as a separator.

Answer (score 1):

Wrapped for legibility:

```
string-join(
    //text()[normalize-space(.)='Consumer buy-to-let Business']/ancestor::*[2]/p, ','
)
```

See: [`fn:string-join`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-string-join).

Note that

- `/parent::*/parent::*` is shorter when written as `/ancestor::*[2]`
- text nodes must always be children of an element, so `//*/text()` is the same as `//text()`

Related reading: [Is it possible to apply normalize-space to all nodes XPath expression finds?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3359512/18771)

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work for me, i've typed it as :
string-join(//text()[normalize-space(.)='Consumer buy-to-let Business']/ancestor::*[2]/p,',')
Im using import.io to test, but it doesn't bring up any results. I do only have one line to enter the XPath

Comment: The relevant portion of my answer is `string-join(someNodes, 'separator')`. If my path does not return anything, use yours. If that does not work, make a cross-check using `string-join(('foo', 'bar'), '.')`. If *that* does not return `'foo.bar'` then there is something wrong with the way your application evaluates XPath expressions.