# what is the way to strip something from text() using xpath?

Tags: python, xpath

i am using an xpath in python  to parse a table from an html file. i am using this xpath :

```
//td//text()
```

This give me output as two strings:

```
['australia', '$3333.99']
```

output i want:

```
['australia', '3333.99']
```

but i want $ sign to be stripped of how can i do that in general using xpath? i have tried `substring-after` but it does not works.

this is how i tried :

```
//td//text()[substring-after(.,'$')]
```

but i got this output:

```
['$3333.99']
```

`Australia` was missing from the result

Comment: The expression you tried is fine in XPath 2.0 but not in XPath 1.0. You should specify which XPath version you are using. Though it doesn't do quite what you want: try `//td//text()/substring-after(.,'$')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from using `translate()` (as posted in the other answer), you can also use [`substring()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/substring) and dynamically determine the beginning of a slice:

```
In [4]: [item.xpath("substring(., starts-with(., '$') + 1)") for item in root.xpath("//td")]
Out[4]: ['australia', '3333.99']
```

By the way, this approach is a bit safer than using `translate()` since, here we are only stripping a single `$` character at the beginning of a string if it exists, but `translate()` would replace all the occurrences of `$` in every `td` text you are extracting. You may get some unwanted side effects.

Note that you have to do it in two steps in any case - the `translate()` or `substring()` functions would not be applied to every node if used like `translate(//td//text(), "$", "")`, references:

- [How to apply the XPath function 'substring-after'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333249/how-to-apply-the-xpath-function-substring-after)
- [Is it possible to apply normalize-space to all nodes XPath expression finds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359512/is-it-possible-to-apply-normalize-space-to-all-nodes-xpath-expression-finds)

Or, you can trim it using Python and [`.lstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip):

```
[item.lstrip("$") for item in root.xpath("//td//text()")]
```

Comment: i am aware of this but i dont want to loop over list because i have more than 500 of them , it makes the function slow . i was looking for a way using xpath mayb using `translate`

Comment: @anekix saw the translate variant and decided to post an alternative approach, check it out

Comment: @anekix also, linked a discussion about why you cannot do it in one go and have to have an extra loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
//td//text()[substring-after(.,'$')]
```

This will evaluate the `text()` in `['australia', '$3333.99']`, and for the 
`australia`, it dose not contains `$`, this will return `false` and will not show in the result

```
[td.xpath('translate(., "$", "")')for td in tree.xpath("//td")]
```

Comment: @anekix xpath is used to locate tag, not modify the tag. yes, xpath path can do the this task, but python `strip` is better choice.

Comment: i have like 500 lists to apply lstrip on its not the big deal i know but i have to do thi for 400 tables so now its 400X500 its a costly loop i think and it slows down my application

Comment: isn't it same ? i meant i have to do a seperate iteration over the list right?

Comment: @anekix yes, it's inevitable

Comment: @anekix I think you should get rid of all `$` in your html file before you use xpath, this is much efficient